# How to add active class to multiple checkbox in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

#### Example

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isActive : false,
    chkGenres : [],
    genres : [
      { "id" : "1", "name" : "Apple" },
      { "id" : "2", "name" : "Banana" },
      { "id" : "3", "name" : "Peach" }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    isChecked(){
      this.isActive = ! this.isActive;
    }
  }
});
```

#### DEMO

Please check my demo

https://jsfiddle.net/byxda8eq/9/

#### What I want

I want to toggle class "active" to li tag when specified checkbox is checked or not.

I can not find a way to do that cuz my brain does not working everyday.

How to?

Comment: What `<li>` tag? What checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using a single `isActive` data option and binding it to all the checkboxes. So, when if any one of them is checked, it toggles the `isActive` value and is it bound to all of them thus all of the li class are changed.

A simple way to resolve this by adding a new property `isActive` to all the objects inside the `genres` array like:

```
genres : [
  { "id" : "1", "name" : "Apple", isActive: false },
  { "id" : "2", "name" : "Banana", isActive: false },
  { "id" : "3", "name" : "Peach", isActive: false }
]
```

and then update the template like:

```
<li v-for="genre in genres" :class="{ active : genre.isActive }">
```

and then update the click method like:

```
@click="isChecked(genre)"
```

and the main method like:

```
isChecked(genre){
  genre.isActive = !genre.isActive;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/uf62cLs0/)